# UIView transitionFromView: how can I do black background during transition?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I use next code.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:viewA toView:viewB duration:1.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        completion: ^(BOOL inFinished) {
                            viewB.hidden = NO;
                            viewA.hidden = YES;
                            //do any post animation actions here
                        }];
```

Transition works OK. I want to set a black background during transition. How can I do this?
Please, see the photo:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with setting the black background color for parent view of animated view.

```
viewB.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: @Voloda2 : Good,Actually It's related with the parent background color ... Right ..