# Change Transition Tint/Fade Colour of UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm switching between two container views in my program with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft as such:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                          duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^{
                            self.timerPage.hidden   = true;
                            self.countdownPage.hidden = false;
                        } completion:nil
         ];
```

It works fine but what bugs me is the fact that my views are faded in and out to black, i would like the  colour instead to be white. I've searched various threads but i couldn't find a solution to this exact problem.

I can't upload an image yet but the image in this question shows exactly what I'm talking about. The view fades to black during transition: [UIView transitionFromView: how can I do black background during transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6493478/5224679)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behavior you want by adding a subview or sublayer to your view with a clear background color and then setting the background color of that to white in your animation block.

```
UIView *whiteView = [[UIView alloc] init];
whiteView.frame = self.button.bounds;
[self.button addSubview:whiteView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^{
    whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}];
```

Comment: That didn't work. I think it's because, regardless of the components of the view, it will be faded to black during the flip transition. I'm just trying to change the colour it fades to during transition. Please take a look at the image in the link i just posted in an edit i made to the question.

Comment: Ah I see. That might not be possible to do using UIViewAnimationOptions. You might try combining different options/animations to see if you can get that effect. If that doesn't work, you can do your own flip animation by animating transforms on the views' layers. If you do something like this:

Comment: `[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
        self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0);
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Finished first pi");
        self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(self.button.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0));
    }];`